# Does Islam consider Jesus to be a prophet and of virgin birth?

Tags: prophet-isa

Does Islam consider Jesus to be a prophet and of virgin birth? Like Moses and Abraham and other prophets Jesus was a prophet. Was Jesus of virgin birth?

Comment: Even the most basic Google search would give you Islam's perspective of Jesus. Given that, and given your argumentative behaviour in comments (now deleted), this doesn't look like a real question and I am closing it as off-topic: **This is not an honest question and we are not a site for argument and debate.**

Comment: A Google search doesn't not necessarily give truth nor does one side determine if a question is real.  The subjects of the question are real, the events are real. The question is focused on what it true. Now: Quran 2:136 ""We believe in Allah, and the revelation given to us, and to Abraham, Isma'il, Isaac, Jacob, and the Tribes, and that given to Moses and Jesus, and that given to (all) prophets from their Lord: We make no difference between one and another of them"" 
Injil, So Jesus said he would die on a cross for mankind's sins. He was decreed a prophets, so He spoke the truth.

Comment: When did Jesus say he would die on a cross for mankind's sins?

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

> قالت رب أنى يكون لي ولد ولم يمسسني بشر قال كذلك الله يخلق ما يشاء إذا
> قضى أمرا فإنما يقول له كن فيكون
>
> She said, "My Lord, how will I have a child when no man has touched
> me?" [The angel] said, "Such is Allah; He creates what He wills. When
> He decrees a matter, He only says to it, 'Be,' and it is.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 3:47](http://legacy.quran.com/3/47)</sup>

> قالت أنى يكون لي غلام ولم يمسسني بشر ولم أك بغيا
> قال كذلك قال ربك هو علي هين ولنجعله آية للناس ورحمة منا وكان أمرا مقضيا
>
> She said, "How can I have a boy while no man has touched me and I have
> not been unchaste?" He said, "Thus [it will be]; your Lord says, 'It is easy for Me, and We will make him a sign to the people and a mercy from Us. And it is a matter [already] decreed.' "
>
> <sup>— [Quran 19:20-21](http://legacy.quran.com/19/20-21)</sup>