# Is the following true about Muslims

Tags: quran

Muslims believe the Quran to be the final revelation of Allah to man, and a completion and confirmation of previous scriptures.

Four of these are mentioned by name in the Quran are 
1.  The Tawra (Torah or the Law) revealed to Musa (Moses). 
2.  The Zabur (Mizmor / Zemirot or Psalms) revealed to Dawud (David).
3.  The Injil (Euangélion / Ewwangelliwon or the Gospel) revealed to Isa (Jesus).
4.  The Quran revealed to Muhammad.

The Quran is divided into chapters called surah in Arabic, and then divided into verses called ayah. And again, Muslims believe the Quran was revealed by God verbally to Muhammad through the angel Gabriel. And that the Quran is “without error”.

Comment: Yes, although this is either common knowledge or easily researchable. Is this a rhetorical question like the [previous](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/54869/) one?

Comment: there is a lot of "common" knowledge of all kinds researchable , some right and some wrong. Would a google search tell which is right or not.

Comment: So what basically is your question?
Do you just want to know that what you wrote above is correct or not ??

Answer (score 0):

1. Muslims believe the Quran to be the final revelation of Allah **to not just mankind but also the jinn kind**
2. Besides the four mentioned by you, many Muslims believe that Prophet Abraham was also given some sort of revelation ([Ṣuḥuf ʾIbrāhīm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrolls_of_Abraham))
3. The Quran is divided into 30 sections (Para) and 114 Surahs (Chapters).
4. Each verse of the Quran is called an ayah (sign)
5. Yes, the Quran was revealed by God verbally to Muhammad primarily through the arch angel Gabriel although there is one incident in the Hadith that Angel Israfil had once interacted with the Prophet to [grant him a wish](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HYAEyUKYzus) (not related to the Quran)
6. The Muslims believe that the Quran is without error. Many things in it have being proven over the centuries after the Prophet's death. And Muslims also believe for the other ayahs, the world and science is yet to advance to understand it (for example no one could have explained the minute details of the formation of an embryo in the womb 1400+ years ago but we have it in the Quran. It is only a few decades science had developed enough to actually allow us to visually observe this phenomenon)

Comment: Corrected ..??...  
Mainly of these are mentioned by name in the Quran are 
1.  The Ṣuḥuf ʾIbrāhīm (Scrolls of Abraham) revealed to Abraham 
2. The Tawra (Torah or the Law) revealed to Musa (Moses). 
3. The Zabur (Mizmor / Zemirot or Psalms) revealed to Dawud (David).
4. The Injil (Euangélion / Ewwangelliwon or the Gospel) revealed to Isa (Jesus).
5. The Quran revealed to Muhammad.

Comment: In fact in point 3) your answer is rather wrong the qur'an is divided into surah and ayat (by Allah and His prophet) all other divisions are man made and have no backup in the teaching of Islam. Among the first who started/ ordered creating/finding such divisions was al-Hajjaj ibn Yousuf a-Taqfi.

Comment: So the previous answer-er who said the sections, is the one who is wrong

Comment: @Medi1Saif @ I do not believe I have made a mistake unless I'm ignorant of the facts. In #3 I state that the Quran is divided into 30 sections (Para) and 114 Surahs (Chapters). No where did I mention if the divisions are divine or man-made. Any modern printed mushaf today will have 30 paras and 114 surahs along with the number ayahs for ease of reading. I understand that earlier copies of mushaf exist without verse numbers, and without chapter classifications. But I see no contradiction here. Please enlighten me if the information I have is erroneous.